# Struggling to append a relative path to my sys.path

Tags: python, relative-path

So there are a lot of pretty similar questions but none of the answers seems to satisfy what I'm looking for.

Essentially I am running a python script using an absolute directory in the command line.
Within this file itself, I want to import a module/file,I currently use an absolute path to do this (`sys.path.append(/....)`.
But I would like to use a relative path, relative to the script itself.
All I seem to be able to do is append a path relative to my present working directory.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to import?

Comment: BTW, I think you should read documentation on packages http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: And this may also help you http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html . I have had the same problem as you when I first came to python.

Comment: Hi, it's just a python file from a directory above where my script is. Am I really using packages?
Currently at the top of my file, it says
    'sys.path.append("/directory/file")

I would like to just put something like
    'sys.path.append("../file")

But that just appends something relative to the pwd I am running the script from (I run it using '/directory1/director2/file.py')

Comment: Don't. Expand the relative path to an absolute path, and append that.

Comment: Well, perhaps for a quick and dirty script it may work @user2564502, but consider it is not a clean solution doing such thing in a bigger project.

Comment: Hi, sorry David, what do you mean by that? I know the file's absolute path - are you saying that I should use that?

Comment: Normally, `sys.path` is modified by **pre**pending a path, because the purpose is to override what *would already* be found - so something needs to come before that in the search order. However, `sys.path` hacks are rarely if ever necessary. Many major Python code projects, spanning hundreds of thousands of lines of code each, get by just fine without them.

Comment: Anyway, the **only** approach that works is to compute an absolute path, because **you do not control** what the path is relative to. Relative paths don't encode any information about what they're "supposed to be" relative to - when you add that information, **that's what an absolute path is**. The only reason you'd *need* a relative path is because "what it's relative to" could *change*; but "location of the script file" is obviously not doing to change, whereas "current working directory" might. As such, this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 72):

The two below alternate possibilities apply to both Python versions 2 and 3. Choose the way you prefer. All use cases are covered.

### Example 1

Module is being imported from a subdirectory (`./bar/baz`) of a directory of currently running module (`/some/path/foo`).

```
main script:      /some/path/foo/foo.py
module to import: /some/path/foo/bar/baz/mymodule.py
```

Add in `foo.py`

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'bar', 'baz'))
from mymodule import MyModule
```

### Example 2

Module is being imported from a subdirectory (`./bar/baz`) of **parent** directory (`/some/path/`) of currently running module (`/some/path/foo`).

```
main script:      /some/path/foo/foo.py
module to import: /some/path/bar/baz/mymodule.py
```

Add in `foo.py`

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.path[0]), 'bar', 'baz'))
from mymodule import MyModule
```

### Explanations

- `sys.path[0]` is `/some/path/foo` in both examples
- `os.path.join('a','b','c')` is more portable than `'a/b/c'`
- `os.path.dirname(mydir)` is more portable than `os.path.join(mydir,'..')`

### See also

Documentation about importing modules:

- in [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)
- in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)