# sys.path.append which main.py will be imported

Tags: python, sys

If I have a project with two files `main.py` and `main2.py`. In `main2.py` I do `import sys; sys.path.append(path)`, and I do `import main`, which `main.py` will be imported? The one in my project or the one in `path` (the question poses itself only if there are two `main.py` obviously)?

Can I force Python to import a specific one?

Comment: try `sys.path.insert(0,path)` so `path` comes first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The one that is in your project.**

According to [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), the import order is:

1. Built-in python modules. You can see the list in the variable `sys.modules`
2. The `sys.path` entries
3. The installation-dependent default locations

Your added directory to `sys.path`, so it depends on the order of entries in `sys.path`.

You can check the order of imports by running this code:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

As you will observe, the first entry of `sys.path` is your module's directory ("project directory") and the last is the one you appended.

**You can force python to use the outer directory by adding it in the beginning of your `sys.path`**:

```
sys.path.insert(0,path)
```

Although I would recommend against having same names for the modules as it is often hard to manage.

Another thing to keep in mind is that you can't import relative paths to your `sys.path`. Check this answer for more information on how to work around that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35259170/6599912

Answer (score 2):

When two paths contain the same module name, using `sys.path.append(path)` isn't going to change the priority of the imports, since `append` puts `path` at the end of the python path list

I'd use

```
sys.path.insert(0,path)
```

so modules from `path` come first

Example: my module `foo.py` imports `main` and there's one `main.py` in the same directory and one `main.py` in the `sub` directory

```
foo.py
main.py
sub/main.py
```

in foo.py if I do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("sub")
import main

print(main.__file__)
```

I get the `main.py` file path of the current directory because `sys.path` always starts by the main script directory.

So I could remove that directory from `sys.path` but it's a bad idea because I could need other modules from there.

Now if I use `insert` instead:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"sub")
import main

print(main.__file__)
```

I get `sub/main.py` as `sub` is the first directory python looks into when searching modules.

Comment: "sys.path always start by the current directory"
Depends what do you mean by "current directory". For me the current (working) directory wasn't in the path at all. The first one was the executable directory.

Comment: Yes, it's rather "the main script directory". The solution doesn't change, though